# Angular 7 data binding being delayed

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, data-binding, geocoding

I am having an issue with Angular's data binding being delayed.

When the value of `this.notAvailable` is changed the `[class.hide]` doesn't update on the frontend until ~5 seconds after the code has been run.

The `console.log` results show immediately with the correct values, this has really been bugging me as to why this is happening.

The code is as follows:

**xxx.ts**

```js
getPostcodeGeo(postcode) {
  postcode = postcode.replace(' ', '');
  this.geocoder.geocode({'address': postcode}, (result, status) => {
    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      this.notAvailable = false;
      console.log(this.notAvailable);
    }
    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.REQUEST_DENIED) {
      this.notAvailable = true;
      console.log(this.notAvailable);
    }
  });
}
```

**xxx.html**

```html
<div [class.hide]="notAvailable">
  <span>Unable to find address</span>
</div>
```

At first I thought is was to do with the geocoder taking a bit of time, but then I added the console.logs to see if there is a delay in the console.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what about adding changeDetectionRef->detectChanges after the console.log?

Comment: This sounds like code is running outside of the Angular zone (i.e. `this.geocoder.geocode({'address': postcode}, (result, status) => { ... probably this code ... })`. If you get the zone injected into your component (i.e. `constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) {}`) and wrap the code in that callback, your issue should be fixed.

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel this is running the code quicker but is constantly returning REQUEST_DENIED.

Comment: Have you tried to `console.log` the `status` to see what is coming back?

Comment: Yes, it is returning REQUEST_DENIED, before it was returning OK on the postcodes I have been testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned above, the issue is that the callback code passed to the `this.geocoder.geocode(...)` method is being executed outside of the Angular zone. When this happens, Angular is not aware of the changes to the `this.notAvailable` property until something else triggers Angular to do a change detection cycle down the road. To fix this, you will need to get a reference to the Angular zone and wrap the code making changes so that Angular knows to do a change detection cycle.

```js
constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) {}

...

getPostcodeGeo(postcode) {
  postcode = postcode.replace(' ', '');
  this.geocoder.geocode({'address': postcode}, (result, status) => {
    this.ngZone.run(() => {
      if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        this.notAvailable = false;
        console.log(this.notAvailable);
      }
      if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.REQUEST_DENIED) {
        this.notAvailable = true;
        console.log(this.notAvailable);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Sorry to be a pain but this is running the code quicker but is constantly returning REQUEST_DENIED from the geocode now.

Comment: @HenslerSoftware have you inspected the request in your browser to see what the result and status sent back are? Running the code in Angular's zone exactly as above shouldn't affect the `result` or `status` values.

Comment: Thats is working sorry. I was having an issue with the API for some reason I randomly get This API project is not authorized to use this API. I have updated the API key now, and this error show every couple of API calls. Is that standard? I'm not making too many calls.